# Applying a regex to stdin

Tags: bash, regular-expression

In programing we often see the use of [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

One of the most common forms is:

```
newText = text.replace( /regex/, 'replacementString' )
```

If **stdin** is `text` and **stdout** is `newText`, what would the bash equivalent be to the above code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For simple uses you can do it like this:

```
newText=${text/SEARCH/replacement}
```

as it is described [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html), but for more complex expressions sed is the way to go as alex described earlier.

Answer (score 6):

The most straightforward answer is [sed](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html)'s `s` command. You need to convert the regexp syntax to [Basic regular expressions](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03), and the substitution will be applied successively on each line. You can use `\1` through `\9` to refer to parenthesized groups in the original string. Add the `g` modifier to replace all occurrences; otherwise only the first occurrence is replaced.

```
sed -e 's/basic regexp/replacement string/g'
```

A more flexible utility is [awk](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html). It too processes its input line by line by default, but you can change the record separator with `-vRS=…` (standard awk wants a single character, or an empty value to mean two or more newlines; Gawk (the GNU version) accepts a regular expression). The `sub` function performs a single replacement, and `gsub` replaces all occurences. The replacement string is interpreted literally except for `\` and `&`; if you want to refer to parenthesized groups, you can use the `match` and `subtring` functions.

```
awk '{gsub(/regexp/, "replacement string")}'
```

Bash has built-in support for regexp matching: `[[ text =~ regexp ]]`. You can construct a replacement text using matched substrings stored in the `BASH_REMATCH` array. Use `read` or `cat` to obtain the input and `printf` to emit the output. The following pseudo-code performs multiple replacements (warning, untested; the code is supposed to perform multiple replacement from left to right as is usual, I hope I got it right).

```
# The end marker must not have a prefix that is a suffix of a match of the regexp,
# and must not start or end with a newline
end_marker='EOF'
text=$(cat; echo "$end_marker")
while [[ $text =~ regexp(.*)$ ]]; then
    printf %s%s "${text%"$BASH_REMATCH[0]"}" "replacement string"
    text=$BASH_REMATCH[$#BASH_REMATCH]
  fi
done
printf %s "${text%"$end_marker"}"
```

(A few words of explanation: the end marker is to avoid trailing newlines being stripped by the command substitution. `${text%"$BASH_REMATCH[0]"}` extracts the part of the text that came before the match. Note that we can't use `^(.*)` at the beginning of the regexp or we'd get the last match instead of the first. After the match, we iterate over the suffix. Finally we print the unmatched leftover, minus the end marker.)

If you're satisfied with wildcard matching and limited replacement text abilities, bash also has `${variable/pattern/replacement}`. Double the first slash to replace all occurrences. Patterns do have the power of regular expressions (but with an unusual syntax) if the `extglob` option is set.

Answer (score 3):

- `man sed`
- `sed s/regex/replacementString/g`

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl`:

```
perl -lpe 's/old/new/g'
```

Comment: I used it without `-l` which chomps lines

Answer (score -1):

you can use tools like `sed` and `awk`, but in my opinion they are very antiquated and only useful for narrowly defined tasks.

a better bet is to redirect STDIN to a perl one-liner or script. perl's regex support is so good that most other languages now support some compatibility with them. there are even `a2p` and `s2p` tools to transform sed and awk directly into perl. using perl allows you to use the entirety of CPAN to help you solve your problems.

and if you don't like perl, you can use python in a similar capacity.

Comment: Providing an example would improve your answer

Comment: `awk` is a Turing complete programming language... How is it narrow?. `sed` is quite an efficient text editor.  "Antiquated" is a value judgement, not a measure of relevance, pertinence or capability.